# Python or Py not found in docker image

Tags: python, docker

Below is my docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y telnet && apt-get install -y ksh  && apt-get install -y curl && apt-get install -y python2.7.x python-dev build-essential && apt-get -y clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
RUN python get-pip.py
RUN pip install pymssql==2.1.3
ENTRYPOINT ['py']
```

I am getting the below error (py not found in docker image)

[image]

I tried replacing 'py' with 'python' and still it complains that 'python' not found in docker image

Comment: You can probably use a python docker image  (https://hub.docker.com/_/python) instead of ubuntu image and save the pain of installing all the python dependencies. Also, try `ENTRYPOINT ["py"]` (py in double quotes)

Comment: What is `py` you want to run? Did you add that to your current path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the entrypoint command you must use double quote like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["py"]
```